# Scalable and High performance message channel

Tags: java, udp, message-queue, multicast

I am developing agents to collect data from different sources, the data should be posted to a channel at high frequency (say every 15 seconds). REST is definitely not a solution. The requirement is clearly fire and forget as status reply is not concerned.

Throughput is more important, message drops are acceptable upto 5%.

Possible solutions I come across are

- Message Bus
- Multicast
- UDP

Any alternatives, please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO High frequency is too fast too see and 15 seconds you can see. It takes about 0.5 seconds to send a message round the world and back again.  You can just about see 15 milli-seconds. And if you are talking about 15 micro-seconds, that is definitely high frequency.  I have a persisted messaging solution with a latency of around 0.1 micro-seconds which is 0.0000001 seconds, but I don't suggest you need that.

If all you need is a message every 15 seconds I would use the simplest solution which comes to mind.  I would try ActiveMQ which I found to be one of the simplest to get working.  You should be able to achieve message rates of up to 20,000 per seconds and decent latencies of about 0.01 seconds and you shouldn't lose any messages.

Comment: Your answer clears the definition of high frequency. Based on the frequency the solution make sense. Is there any alternates than the ones listed?

Comment: @NageswaraRao The list is too long to mention here. I would use the simplest to use solution you can find.

Comment: I am fine to go through different approaches. If possible please email or point me the resource